# How *should* we have known to invent homological algebra?

Tags: homological-algebra

Previously I asked [How did we know to invent homological algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/416743/), because I was under the misapprehension that concrete examples of long exact sequences had been a major motivation for developing homological algebra.  I've now learned to my surprise that they were invented in the 1940's, long after other parts of homological algebra were better-established.

In the comments there, @Qiaochu Yuan [suggested](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/416743/how-did-we-know-to-invent-homological-algebra/416771?noredirect=1#comment893152_416771) I ask the variant question How *should* we have known to invent homological algebra?; taking his suggestion, I'm asking it now.

Of course this question is open to a considerable amount of interpretation.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the extension problem in group theory: we say that $K$ is an extension of $G$ by $A$ is there is a surjective homomorphism $\phi: K \to G$ with $\ker(\phi) = A$.  How many extension of $G$ are there by $A$ up to some good notion of equivalence?

Suppose we have such an extension in which all involved groups are abelian.  Consider that $\hom(G,A)$ naturally injects into $\hom(G,K)$ so we can form the quotient $\hom(G,K)/\hom(G,A)$.  In addition, the extension $\phi$ induces a map $\phi_*:\hom(G,K) \to \hom(G,G)$ by composition.  It is clear that kernel of this map *includes* the image of $\hom(G,A)$ in $\hom(G,K)$, because $\ker(\phi) = A$.  So is $\hom(G,G) \simeq \hom(G,K)/\hom(G,A)$?

No: just consider $G = \mathbb{Z}_2$, $K = \mathbb{Z}$ and $A = 2\mathbb{Z}$.

We could phrase the extension problem differently: given (abelian) groups $G$ and $A$, an extension of $G$ by $A$ is a group $K$ admitting an injection $i: A \to K$ and a surjection $\phi: K \to A$ such that $\ker(\phi) = i(A)$.  Consider that $\hom(K,A)$ naturally surjects onto $\hom(A,A)$ by restriction.  Form the quotient $\hom(K,A)/\hom(A,A)$.  In addition, the map $\phi$ induces a map $\phi_*: \hom(K,A) \to \hom(G,A)$ by composition.  It is clear that the kernel of this map *includes* $\hom(A,A)$ because $\ker(\phi) = A$.  So is $\hom(G,A) \simeq \hom(K,A)/\hom(A,A)$?

No: just consider the example (reframed to this extension problem).

What gives?  More specifically, what are the relevant cokernels?

The first difficulty arises from *lifting*: $G \simeq K/A$, but there are self-maps of $G$ which don't lift to maps from $G$ to $K$.  The second difficulty arises from *extension*: there are maps from $G$ to $A$ which don't extend to maps from $K$ to $A$.

As groups are $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, you could try modules over your other favorite ring.  What if you try to change ring via tensor product?

---

As for topology, your original question has an answer from Sammy Black which uses no exact sequences.  Again, the issue is that a particular construction does not play nicely with quotients.

This is my best attempt at an answer.  The lesson to me is that it's a good idea to think through these homological constructions without reference to an exact sequence.  If you view the sequences as organizational tools, then "the functor $\mathcal{F}$ is not exact" just means that "the functor $\mathcal{F}$ does not work nicely with out organizational scheme."  But relative homology and group extension are both quite natural without any fancy diagrams.