# Purely algebraic context in which homology arises naturally?

Tags: homological-algebra, intuition, big-picture

I know that homology is most commonly introduced from a topological context (and/or Stokes theorem related context), but in say a homological algebra course/text, you are just given the definitions (chain complexes, the $d^2=0$ condition, and then the image over kernel construction) with very little/insufficient (in my eyes) motivation.

Of course it would be inconvenient to drag in all the historical motivation from topology, so I’m wondering if there’s a purely algebraic problem or question from which the ideas of (co)homology “obviously” arise, and if so, what’s the most natural or elementary such question.

For example a common intuition for homological algebra is that it “measures how far a chain complex is from being exact”, but even a student decently far along in their introductory algebra class (say having gone through group/ring/field theory and Galois theory and then developing module theory via “analogy from linear algebra”) does not know to care about chain complexes or measuring their exactness (or lack thereof).

I know that short exact sequences come quite naturally from the 1st isomorphism theorem, but I wonder if there are other algebraic “clues” that indicate that generally the $d^2=0$ condition and image over kernel construction are fruitful/key directions of investigation.

EDIT: it appears that a very similar question has been asked before, here [How *should* we have known to invent homological algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/417778/how-should-we-have-known-to-invent-homological-algebra). I would still be interested in answers to either!

Comment: Do you know about relation of semidirect products with $H^1$ and central extensions with $H^2$? [Also](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/143031/the-teichm%C3%BCllers-algebraic-interpretation-of-h3-in-group-cohomology/143039).

Comment: Galois cohomology provides some examples (Normal basis theorem, Hilbert theorem 90, (Weak) Mordell-Weil) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_cohomology

Comment: Deformation theory of algebras (of different kinds) naturally leads to the notion of cohomology (and other beasts).

Comment: Tensor product is right-exact, Hom is left-exact, when are they exact? How far are they from being exact? This is measured by a long exact sequence via (co-)homology groups, namely Tor and Ext.